# How to import a python file to be executed on schedule time. using schedule

Tags: python

I am trying to use schedule to schedule jobs every work day at a certain time and execute a file when its time. The problem is that it runs the validate.py on schedule and off schedule. I want it to run only when the time is 9:09 .

```
from dateutil import rrule
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
import schedule
import requests
import validate.py

def job():
    execfile("validate.py")


start_hour = datetime.strptime("09:09:26","%H:%M:%S")
end_hour = start_hour + timedelta(hours=7)

for t in rrule.rrule(rrule.HOURLY, dtstart=start_hour, until=end_hour):
    schedule.every().monday.at(t.strftime("%H:%M")).do(job)
    schedule.every().tuesday.at(t.strftime("%H:%M")).do(job)
    schedule.every().wednesday.at(t.strftime("%H:%M")).do(job)
    schedule.every().thursday.at(t.strftime("%H:%M")).do(job)
    schedule.every().friday.at(t.strftime("%H:%M")).do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pytz
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

def job():
    execfile("validate.py")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    timez = pytz.timezone(YOUR_TIMEZONE)
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler(timezone=timez)
    scheduler.add_job(job, "cron", day_of_week="1-5", hour=9, minute=9)
    scheduler.start()
```

BlockingScheduler might be useful on your case. the parameter: YOUR_TIMEZONE just like`'Asia/Shanghai'`

Comment: thank you, i am trying this but some problem hapening with pytz although its installed.

Comment: i am very new to python but i just need it for a project

Comment: @maja Otherwise you just ignore the timez. like: scheduler = BlockingScheduler() The code is still fine but you may focus on the server time.

Comment: it finally worked, just like your code but using exec(open("").read()) instead.

Comment: and the pytz problem was solved because it was downloading by mistake into an old version of python

Comment: how can i keep it working for a number of hours a day ? like 7 hours everyday?

Comment: @maja Just like scheduler.add_job(job, 'interval', hours=1) that means run job hoursly. but you should try to combine two type of job trigger type so that can set the time range and frequency.

Comment: @maja Assumed that you want to run the job from 9:30 to 15:30 hoursly every working day. One way to set the schedule is: scheduler.add_job(job, "cron", day_of_week="1-5", hour='9-15', minute='30')